# Toggling between dark/light mode Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I just can't figure it out. I want to change background with Switch, but it works only the first time, doesn't work on subsequent clicks.
Here is code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-shaw-2tfk5

Could someone enlighten me what is going on? I'm using Material UI with React

minimal reproducible example:
this is my App component

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Container, Switch, CssBaseline } from "@material-ui/core";

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    background: {
      default: "hsl(230, 17%, 14%)"
    }
  }
});

const lightTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light",
    background: {
      default: "hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"
    }
  }
});

const App = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");

  const selectedTheme = mode === "dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme;

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={selectedTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <Switch onChange={() => setMode(mode === "light" ? "dark" : "light")} />
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I added example, so you can remove that downvote

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Material UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#user-preference), to switch between light and dark, they suggest `useMemo` to create a new theme on demand:

```
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";

function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");

  const theme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        palette: {
          type: mode,
          background: {
            dark: "hsl(230, 17%, 14%)",
            light: "hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"
          }
        }
      }),
    [mode]
  );

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <Switch onChange={() => setMode(mode === "light" ? "dark" : "light")} />
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

This works even when using `StrictMode`.

The reason it doesn't work with `StrictMode` when defined outside of the component is addressed in [a Github issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/23334), which states that this behaviour should be fixed in v5 (still in beta).

Answer (score 1):

not sure why, but removing StrictMode in index.js fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can either put your variables for themes inside your App component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-lederberg-8v7tx?file=/src/App.js
or dynamically change theme properties:
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-ives-587fm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, this works, but still I'm not sure why my version doesn't work. Theme is not something I would want to keep in App component, preferably in different file altogether

Comment: Please include relevant details into the answer itself, not only on off-site resources.

Comment: you can see even from my console.logs that correct theme is passed to provider

Answer (score 0):

The below will default to the user's system preference while also allowing the user to toggle modes.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Brightness4Icon from "@mui/icons-material/Brightness4";
import Brightness7Icon from "@mui/icons-material/Brightness7";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";

const ThemePaletteModeContext = React.createContext({
  toggleThemePaletteMode: () => {}
});

const ToggleThemePaletteMode = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const themePaletteModeContext = React.useContext(ThemePaletteModeContext);
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        width: "100%",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "left",
        bgcolor: "background.default",
        color: "text.primary"
      }}
    >
      <IconButton
        sx={{ ml: 1 }}
        onClick={themePaletteModeContext.toggleThemePaletteMode}
        color="inherit"
      >
        {theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? (
          <Brightness7Icon />
        ) : (
          <Brightness4Icon />
        )}
      </IconButton>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const isSystemDarkMode = useMediaQuery("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
  const [themePaletteMode, setThemePaletteMode] = React.useState(
    isSystemDarkMode ? "dark" : "light"
  );

  const themePaletteModeContextProvider = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleThemePaletteMode: () => {
        setThemePaletteMode((prevMode) =>
          prevMode === "light" ? "dark" : "light"
        );
      }
    }),
    []
  );

  const themeProvider = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        palette: {
          mode: themePaletteMode
        }
      }),
    [themePaletteMode]
  );

  return (
    <ThemePaletteModeContext.Provider value={themePaletteModeContextProvider}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themeProvider}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <ToggleThemePaletteMode />
        Hello World
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ThemePaletteModeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]